# Compare two columns in excel: One to One Mapping

Tags: excel, vba

If I have two columns in excel (separate sheets):

```
Column 1  Column 2

A            B
B            E
C            F
C            G
F            C
```

I'd like to identify which items in column 1 exist in column 2 and vice versa (ie B, C, F). This can be done either with conditional formatting or VLOOKUP.

However, column 1 has 2 C's. I want an exact 1 to 1 match. So, I'd like the first C in Column 1 to match with the C in column 2, but I don't want the second C in column 1 to match with the same C in column 2.

Is there any way I can use macros (or anything else) to identify 1 to 1 matches?

Answer (score 1):

What about `COUNTIF` with mixed references?

Something like this:

In `C2`: `=COUNTIF(B:B,A2)>=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)`

In `D2`: `=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)>=COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)`

[image]

These can easily be made into conditional formatting rules:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the answer of @BigBen is Brillant. If you want a macro that match two column in two different sheet you can try this code:

```
Sub test()

Dim numRowsSheet1, numRowsSheet2 As Integer
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")


With ws1
'count how many rows are used on the A column sheet1
 numRowsSheet1 = .Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
End With
'MsgBox numRows

With ws2
'count how many rows are used on the A column sheet1
 numRowsSheet2 = .Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
End With

'macth column A sheet1 with sheet2
Call myMatch(ws1, ws2, numRowsSheet1, numRowsSheet2)

'macth column A sheet2 with sheet1
Call myMatch(ws2, ws1, numRowsSheet2, numRowsSheet1) ' call my function

End Sub

'function where i do the match
Function myMatch(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal wss As Worksheet, ByVal numRows As Integer, ByVal numRowss As Integer)

Dim myArray() As String
Dim i, j As Integer

ReDim myArray(numRows - 1) 'into this array i put the data used

For i = 1 To numRows

    With ws
        
      myArray(i - 1) = .Cells(i, 1) 'put into array the items of the sheet
        
    End With
    
Next i

j = 0
'macth items present into sheet
Do
For i = 1 To numRowss

    With wss
        
      If .Cells(i, 1) = myArray(j) Then
      
        .Cells(i, 2) = "true" ' next cell it writes true
        .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow color
        j = j + 1
        If j > numRows - 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
      End If
        
    End With
    
Next i
j = j + 1
Loop Until j > numRows - 1
End Function
```

The result is:
sheet1
[image]

and into sheet2 is
[image]

in italian VERO = TRUE.
Hope this help you.